# Insert results of multiple queries in one array

Tags: php

This is how my PHP file looks right now:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors','1'); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';

    if (connect()){
        global $conn;
        $param = array();

        $queryOBParam = "SELECT p,q,b
                         FROM params
                         WHERE faculty = 'OB'";             

        $checkRes = $conn->prepare($queryOBParam);
        $checkRes->execute();
        $checkRes->bind_result($pOB,$qOB,$bOB);

        while ($checkRes->fetch()){ 
            $temp = [
                'p'=>$pOB,
                'q'=>$qOB,
                'b'=>$bOB
            ];

            array_push($param,$temp);
        }

        echo json_encode($param);
    }
?>
```

I wish to insert the results of the query below in the array *$param* since I need all of them in my application at one go.

```
$queryTotVoters = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalVoters
                   FROM regVoter";
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: write same code for this query as you have written for your first query, what is the problem ?

Comment: you have already used `array_push()`, I think you can use the same as `array_push($param, $queryTotVoters);`

Comment: are the tables `params` and `totalVoters` related? does one have the foreign key of the other?

Comment: @Cashbee No, they are not related at all

Comment: @Mag in this case you should tell us how your desired array would look like

Comment: @Cashbee Something like [{"p":293,"q":433,"b":10, "totalVoters":27}]

Comment: but the totalVoters value will be the same for all. are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @Cashbee Yes, I know but this is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you said that your desired end array should look like this: `[{"p":293,"q":433,"b":10, "totalVoters":27}]`.
Here is a way you can accomplish that, but keep in mind that however many entries the array will have, the totalVoters value will be the same for all, because the query `SELECT COUNT(*) as totalVoters FROM regVoter` does not have a WHERE clause like `WHERE param = X`.

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors','1'); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';

    if (connect()){
        global $conn;
        $param = array();
        $totalVoters = 0;

        // get totalVoters from regVoter
        $queryTotalVoters = "SELECT COUNT(*) as totalVoters FROM regVoter";

        $checkRes = $conn->prepare($queryTotalVoters);
        $checkRes->execute();
        $checkRes->bind_result($resTotalVoters);

        while ($checkRes->fetch()){ 
            $totalVoters = $resTotalVoters;
        }


        $queryOBParam = "SELECT p,q,b
                         FROM params
                         WHERE faculty = 'OB'";             

        $checkRes = $conn->prepare($queryOBParam);
        $checkRes->execute();
        $checkRes->bind_result($pOB,$qOB,$bOB);

        while ($checkRes->fetch()){ 
            $param[] = [
                'p'=>$pOB,
                'q'=>$qOB,
                'b'=>$bOB,
                'totalVoters'=>$totalVoters
            ];
        }

        echo json_encode($param);
    }
?>
```

<sub>small note: I have never used bind_result() and fetch(), in fact objectorientated Mysqli in general, so I just copied it from the existing query. Therefore my code may have errors</sub>

Edit: added initialisation of $totalVoters

Comment: There are no errors, this works perfectly fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Mag I just found obsolete code I added, remove `$row = ` from the new `while ($checkRes->fetch()){ `-loop. I'm glad it works, cheers.

Comment: I just realised I have the results of 2 more queries to include in this array. Can you advise me on how to do that?

Comment: You should be able to do that yourself now, the same way like I added totalVoters here. ;)

Comment: That's what I did but I get `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean`.

Comment: use google or your common sense to find that error. You can do it :)